# What do 肯定 and 一定 do in 这些行动是积极的，值得肯定，对于减少烟毒有一定的意义?

Tags: translation, usage

The sentence I'm having trouble figuring out is

> 这些行动是积极的，值得肯定，对于减少烟毒有一定的意义。

Regarding `值得肯定` does it mean it's worth acknowledging as a positive action ?

As for `一定的意` does it mean has some significance？

If it helps to provide more context for the sentence, the following sentence is

> 但要看到，要减少烟毒，光靠社会的力量是不够的。

Answer (score 2):

The whole sentence is : 这些行动是积极的(These actions are positive), 值得肯定(worthy of recognition),对于减少烟毒有一定的意义。(have certain significance to reduce the smoke toxicity).

Here 肯定 means recognition by people or society.比如 他的事迹得到了社会的肯定。
There is **no** 一定的意 in Chinese
一定的意义 means certain significance.比如 你的建议对我有一定的价值，我会好好想想。(Your suggestions has some certain value for me, and I will think over it.)